# How to use an intermediate file in Makefile correctly?

Tags: make

Consider the following scenario:

```
tempfile: bar
    generate tempfile (using bar)

foo: tempfile
    generate foo (using bar)
```

The thing is like this: `foo` is generated using `tempfile`. `tempfile` is - well - a file which is only needed in the generation of `foo`. In addition, `tempfile` contains some data taken from `bar`, (which is not a temporary file) so whenever `bar` changes, the tempfile should change also, and in turn effect `foo`.

Now, when running `make foo`, I only want `foo` to be built when `bar` is changed. What actually happens is that Make removes the tempfile (which I don't mind by itself), and then it builds foo every single time, even though `bar` has not changed.

Any advice?

Comment: “generate foo (using bar)” suggests that tempfile isn’t needed to generate foo; is that the case?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: So it should really be “generate foo (using tempfile)”, shouldn’t it?

Comment: Also, are you using implicit rules? Without that, Make shouldn’t remove `tempfile`, unless there’s some other rule that removes it.

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` only needs `bar`, then you can drop the `tempfile` prerequisite:

```
foo: bar
        generate foo (using bar)
```

If `foo` needs `tempfile`, and `tempfile` is only used as an intermediate file, you can ask (GNU) Make to keep it by [marking it as precious](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html):

```
.PRECIOUS: tempfile

tempfile: bar
        generate tempfile

foo: tempfile
        generate foo
```

Another possibility, if `tempfile` is necessary, would be to not treat `tempfile` as a separate target:

```
foo: bar
        generate tempfile
        generate bar
```

Comment: please see the edit